# Rotating n-Dimensional Vector about another n-Dimensional Vector

Tags: geometry, vectors, rotations

I have been looking for long time but I could not find exactly what I am looking for.

I need to rotate a n-dimensional vector **about/around** another with same dimensions by some angle, where **n>3**.

I know how to achieve this in 3D. But (just for example) I am looking for a generalization of Rodrigues' rotation formula in higher dimensions.

Please note that I don't want to rotate that n-dimensional vector to the direction of another, nor rotating it around some axis or arbitrary.

Any help or reference is very much appreciated.

Comment: It's not always possible to rotate around axes in higher dimensions, in particular in *even*-numbered dimensions. Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space) for example.

Comment: Generally speaking, rotations occur in _planes_. 3-D space is special in that rotations always have a fixed line—the rotation axis. This is not generally true in higher-dimensional spaces, as the previous comment mentions.

Comment: In the ambient spaces where it is possible to have a single fixed line, you’ll need to decide exactly what it is you mean by rotating about this line—there’s a lot more wiggle room, so to speak, and the transformation is not uniquely defined by just an axis and angle as it is in 3D.