# Contraction Map Function

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be two vectors $\neq 0$.

Let $\overline{f}(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \frac{\vec{x} + \vec{y}}{2}$ be a generic average function.

Now let $d$ be the Euclidean Distance, then:

$d(\overline{f}(\vec{x}, \vec{y}), \overline{f}(\vec{y}, \vec{x})) <  k d(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$ where $k \in ]0,1]$ will always hold true.

---

For example:

Let $\vec{x} = [1,2,3]$ and $\vec{y} = [3,4,5] \implies \thinspace \overline{f}(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \overline{f}(\vec{y}, \vec{x}) = [2, 3, 4]$

Then $d(\overline{f}(\vec{x}, \vec{y}), \overline{f}(\vec{y}, \vec{x})) = 0 <  k d(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) \in ]0, 5.19]$

---

Can we say that $\overline{f}$ is a contraction map function?

Many Thanks.

Comment: $\bar{f}(x)$ doesn't make sense as a notation: $\bar{f}$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$. So it's not clear what you mean by $d(\bar{f}(x),\bar{f}(y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way  you have defined $$\bar {f} (\vec {x}, \vec {y})=\frac{ \vec {x}+ \vec {y} }{2}$$ we have $$ \bar {f} (\vec {x}, \vec {y})=\bar {f} (\vec {y}, \vec {x})$$

Thus the distance $$d(\bar {f} (\vec {x}, \vec {y}),\bar {f} (\vec {y}, \vec {x}))=0$$

Which makes your question trivial.

Please make sure that what you asked is what your really meant to ask.

Comment: Thanks. Okay it is trivial. Though, does this function follow the contraction map rule? That's basically my question.

Comment: Yes it is a contraction and a very strong one.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3247660/rotating-n-dimensional-vector-about-another-n-dimensional-vector)